# Express $x^4-x^3+2x-10$ and $x^2-x+1$ as a linear combination of $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

I've basically applied the Euclidian Algorithm for computing the gcd of $f=x^4-x^3+2x-10$ and $g=x^2-x+1$ . So,

$$\begin{align}x^4-x^3+2x-10 &= (x^2-x+1)(x^2-1)+(x-9)\\
x^2-x+1&=(x-9)(x+8) +73.  \end{align}$$

The solution says $\displaystyle\gcd(f,g)=g(x^3+8x^2-x-7)\left(\frac{1}{73}\right)-f(x+8)\left(\frac{1}{73}\right).$

I don't see when or how the division by $73$ was made, also how the polynomial $x^3+8x^2-x-7$ was obtained. I know how to do this for integers, but for some reason I cannot work it out with polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get, by the *Extended Euclidean algorithm*,
$$73=(x^3+8x^2-x-7)g(x)-(x+8)f(x) $$
there seems to be a sign error in the coefficient of $f(x)$. Then you divide both sides by $73$. The g.c.d. is defined up to a unit, but conventionally, we generally ask for a *monic* polynomial.

Comment: So the gcd in this case is $1$? Would it say be, $73$ if we were in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: That's absolutely right.